# Caching the last tab used

Tags: feature-request

I find myself often doing the following things:
a) type d3.js in the search textfield to search to d3.js related questions
b) click on the tab newest (default is "relevance" tab)

I wonder if it makes sense to improve the usability to have a shortcut for that.
a) is necessary since there is no group solely for d3.js
but b) could be avoided if my preference (the "newest" tab) would be cached and directly applied. Alternatively, it could be set in the preferences.

Does that suggestion make sense or is there any shortcut right now?

Comment: There is a tag for d3.js, so I think what you're looking for is the tag page: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/d3.js

Comment: Thanks the clarification! I shouldn't have mentioned two things. But the tab caching is my main point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just like Google, the raw search functionality tries to find the most relevant information pertaining to your search. You can change the tab afterwards, or you can bookmark a direct link

> https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=d3.js

Note, that search is a regular string search. The system doesn't know that you really mean the tag. As [Mike McCaughan](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/287243/caching-the-last-tab-used#comment161216_287243) says, there is a [d3.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/d3.js) tag.

Clicking on that tag will bring you to the tag's post listing, which defaults to "newest", and will store your last used tab for the next run.

You can also get to this page by typing `[d3.js]` in the search bar (you can read about more advanced searches on the [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/searching)). You will get a url looking like this:

> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/d3.js

If you change the tab you are looking at and reload the url it should bring you to that tab again.

---

Now, do I agree with this? I actually do. If I was searching for any particular random string I would want to see the most relevant data. In your case, where I assume you really want to see the newest posts for a *tag*, you can use the direct method which is more appropriate.